# java.io.File.setReadable(false) has no effect inside docker

Tags: java, file, docker

The following code succeeds on Ubuntu 18.04 with OpenJDK 8, but fails inside the Docker image `maven:3-jdk-8-slim` which is based on OpenJDK 8:

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
System.out.println(String.format("system property user.home: %s",
        userHome));
File file = new File(userHome, "file");
if(!file.createNewFile()) {
    throw new IOException("test arrangement failed");
}
if(!file.setReadable(false)) {
    throw new IOException("test arrangement failed");
}
assertFalse(file.canRead());
```

Failure details:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:64)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:74)
    at de.richtercloud.docker.java.file.readability.TheTest.testSomeMethod(TheTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

which refers to the `assertFalse(file.canRead())` assertion. This assertion should pass because `file.setReadable(false)` returned `true` and thus succeeded.

I reproduced the issue in a SSCCE with the Docker-based GitLab CI, so that detailed output can be found at https://gitlab.com/krichter/docker-java-file-readability/-/jobs/203311757. The SSCCE does not contain more information than the above code excerpt, but makes local investigation easier.

I'm looking for an explanation, not a workaround.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation of `File.canRead()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead--) contains a note that its result may be confusing:

> `public boolean canRead()`
>
> Tests whether the application can read the file denoted by this
>   abstract pathname. **On some platforms it may be possible to start the
>   Java virtual machine with special privileges that allow it to read
>   files that are marked as unreadable. Consequently this method may
>   return `true` even though the file does not have read permissions.**

Under docker processes usually run as root giving them privileges unseen by regular users.

Proof that root can read files lacking read permission:

```
$ echo abcd > somefile
$ ls -l somefile 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leon leon 5 Aug 26 21:43 somefile

$ cat somefile
abcd

$ chmod a-rw somefile 
$ ls -l somefile 
---------- 1 leon leon 5 Aug 26 21:43 somefile

$ cat somefile
cat: somefile: Permission denied

$ sudo cat somefile
abcd
```

Answer (score 3):

I've seen similar results. Files.getPosixFilePermissions will return the expected values, but Files.isReadable and File canRead will return true when false is "expected"

Adding the userID to the docker command line fixes it for me. Possibly it;s the default user of root that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found a work arround for this issue.

In your docker, if it's possible with your linux image, you will have to create a non admin user, then 'su' with this user and launch all your commands you need as this user.

Here is an exemple that only work if you are not an admin or root user:

```
# useradd -m myUser
# su - myUser
$ pwd
/home/myUser
$ cat <<EOF > Test.java
> import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("Test");
    final File nonReadableFile = new File(tempDir.toFile(), "nonReadableFile.txt");
    System.out.println(nonReadableFile.getAbsolutePath());


    nonReadableFile.createNewFile();
    System.out.println(nonReadableFile.canRead());
    nonReadableFile.setReadable(false);
    System.out.println(nonReadableFile.canRead());
  }
}
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > EOF
$ javac Test.java
$ java Test
/tmp/Test2125736191041151487/nonReadableFile.txt
true
false
```

Comment: I am glad you tried to provide an answer, but it was specifically requested to provide a good solution and not a workaround. In fact, there is already an accepted answer with 12 upvote. Thank you anyway.